# Jquery-sortable does not let add child to sibling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to add child in the sibling in Jquery SOrtable .

But it does not allow .

what I want is something like this

```
1.Item
   1.child1
      1.child-child1
   2.child2
2.Item
   1.child1
      1.child-child1
```

My code is something like this

```
var group = $("ol.serialization").sortable({
  group: 'serialization',
  delay: 500,
});
$("ol.simple_with_no_drop").sortable({
  group: 'serialization',
  drop: false
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <ol class="serialization vertical">
        <li>
          <i class="icon-move"></i> Item 1
          <ol>
            <li>
              Item 1
              <ol></ol>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>

      </ol>
      <pre id="serialize_output2"></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h2>Workflow</h2>
    <ol class="simple_with_no_drop vertical">
      <li class="highlight">
        <i class="icon-move"></i> Item 1
      </li>
      <li class="highlight">
        <i class="icon-move"></i> Item 2
      </li>
      <li class="highlight">
        <i class="icon-move"></i> Item 3
      </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <h2>Actions</h2>
    <ol class="simple_with_no_drop vertical">
      <li class="highlight">
        <i class="icon-move"></i> Item 1
      </li>
      <li class="highlight">
        <i class="icon-move"></i> Item 2
      </li>
      <li class="highlight">
        <i class="icon-move"></i> Item 3
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8n6anL4o/)

Am I doing something wrong here?, Or Sort-able doesn't allow to do that ?

Comment: You want to drag items to the 'Workflow' list ?

Comment: from workflow list to the list on the left side

Comment: Which "left side" ? The first list with the 'serialization' class ?

Comment: to `serialization` class

Comment: It seems to be working. At least on your fiddle I can drag items from 'workflow 'to the 'serialization' with no issues.

Comment: Try to do the same relation I have shown in the question like make two parents and try addig child of child for both

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin page :

> There is no on-the-fly creation of sublists. Only list items that
>   contain a sublist are drop targets.

You can only add child items to  **Item 1**, since it's the only with a sublist - the empty ol element.

Comment: @RCosta thank I got the solution , We can create the sublist in any Item1 or 2 Ill post the answer soon